# How to fix this search method

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following in my model to search for a string entered by a user:

```
def self.find_products(product="")

    find(:all, :select => 'product_id, name', :order => "name", :conditions => ["name like ? and locale =?", "%#{product.capitalize}%", I18n.locale])
  end
```

But it only works if the string is one word.
If the string contains two or more words such as "card guides" it returns nothing even if those are the exact words in the name.

How can I do this search properly.

Rails 3 Ruby 1.9.2

Update

It turns out that its a Postgresql syntax. I needed to user iLIKE for case insensitivity. Then it worked better. I still like the answer below as it also helped to refine my syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey i am also using this type of search logic in mine project, I had done in this way . If you want to try then look if it might helps you -:

```
class << self
   def search(query)
    product = "%#{query}%"
    where("name LIKE ? AND locale =?", product,I18n.locale)
   end
end
```

Thanks

Comment: Thanks Vivek that helps a lot

Answer (score 0):

I notice that you're using capitalize.  Are you sure that the product name is being formatted in the exact same way that you're storing the data?  Could it be that the code is returning "Card guides" but your data expects "Card Guides"?